# HttpSession Wrapper Class

Tags: php, object-oriented, classes, session

Are there any aspects I could improve of my `HttpSession` wrapper class?

Other suggestions are also welcome.

```
namespace Http;

class HttpSession
{
    private $data;

    public function __construct($name = null, array $iniSettings = [])
    {
        if ($name) {
            session_name($name);
        }

        foreach ($iniSettings as $key => $value) {
            ini_set($key, $value);
        }
    }

    public function findParameter($name)
    {
        $this->start();

        return isset($this->data[$name]) ? $this->data[$name] : null;
    }

    public function setParameter($name, $value)
    {
        $this->start();

        $this->data[$name] = $value;
    }

    public function unsetParameter($name)
    {
        $this->start();

        unset($this->data[$name]);
    }

    public function regenerateId($deleteOldSessionFile = true)
    {
        $this->start();

        session_regenerate_id($deleteOldSessionFile);
    }

    public function destroy()
    {
        $this->start();

        $this->data = [];

        if (isset($_COOKIE[session_name()])) {
            $scParams = session_get_cookie_params();

            setcookie(
                session_name(), '', time() - 3600,
                $scParams['path'],
                $scParams['domain'],
                $scParams['secure'],
                isset($scParams['httponly'])
            );
        }

        session_destroy();
    }

    private function start()
    {
        if (isset($this->data)) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
            session_start();
        }

        $this->data = &$_SESSION;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things I see:

- Work in the constructor - Don't do work in the constructor. Ideally the only things that should be in the constructor are assignments.
- DRY - Why are you repeating `$this->start()` all over the place?
- What's up with that `destroy()` method? You're doing stuff there other than destroying the session! Why?
- Your `session_start()` should happen once, in the constructor.
- It would be more flexible if you passed the `$_SESSION` array as a parameter in the constructor, rather than relying on globals.

Comment: I have `$this->start()` as lazy initialization. I don't see the point of actually starting a session (`session_start()`) when there is no actual interaction with the session cookie that belongs to it. The `destroy()` method destroys the entire session, including the session cookie. Thing is, the `$_SESSION` array superglobal isn't available until *after* I've called `session_start()`, so it's not injectable. Otherwise I would have to call `session_start()` outside of the class, just to be able to inject it.

Comment: If you've initiated the Session object, you're interacting with the session by definition. It's the job of whoever called the Session object to determine when to start the session, not of the Session object itself.

Comment: The cookie doesn't have to be destroyed. `session_destroy` is plenty.

Comment: In that case, I'd call `session_start()` as part of every page load in the bootstrap stage. It costs practically nothing, and prevents repetition, even at the slight cost of leaking abstraction. PHP's sessions are kind of broken, so you can't really help it. Think about someone extending your class, he would have to dig into the code to realize why his session isn't working (because he has to call `$this->start()` every time!)